# Boot hangs after sddm removal

Tags: boot-repair, sddm

I recently installed sddm, but after trying and not liking it decided to uninstall it. However, on a restart, the system hangs before getting to a login screen. I can't access anything in the system now, and I have important files i can't delete so i can't reinstall my OS. Can anybody help?

Comment: What version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using? Can you still log in at one of the non-GUI ttys ?

Comment: I'm using the latest zorin core. How would I log in that way?

Comment: I can log in using the tty, but I have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Zorin forum.  (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Zorin so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up logging into the tty, installing sddm again, then configuring it to not use sddm on default. Thanks for the help!